# Setting style key to static ResourceKey locks up intellisense autocomplete whenever it included in the auto listed members

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

## Summary

When assigning a style's `x:Key` to a static `ResourceKey`, the XAML intellisense locks up the autocomplete field if the item is included. The item appears as a blank (no name) item and causes a lock-up of pressing any keyboard keys while within the autocomplete box besides `Arrow Keys` and `Delete`. Can't press `Enter`, can't continue typing the name of the resource, just have to paste it in from somewhere else or double-click it in the list. This is obviously very annoying.

I've tried this on 2 computers (1 without any extensions installed) and in Visual Studio 2015 and 2013 and tinkered with various `Text Editor` settings, but no good. I recreated the project from scratch to see if it was just bad caching data or something, but still no good. People seemed to have similar issues when using Resharper, but disabling that and clearing the cache on the computer that did have Resharper installed didn't fix it either.

Since I know this is a common method as to how to assign `ResourceKey`'s to templates/styles and I can't find anything on my specific problem, I figure I must be doing something wrong here. But no matter how simple I made the project or how many small changes I made to it, the problem persisted.

[image]

## Code

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:WpfTestApp.Theme"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Static theme:SharedStyleKeys.ButtonBaseStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ButtonBaseStyleKeyThatWorks" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonBaseStyleKeyThatWorks}" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static theme:SharedStyleKeys.ButtonBaseStyleKey}}" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource <!--Type here-->}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Theme/SharedStyleKeys.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfTestApp.Theme
{
    public static class SharedStyleKeys
    {
        private static ComponentResourceKey buttonBaseStyleKey = new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(SharedStyleKeys), (object)"ButtonBaseStyleKey");
        public static ResourceKey ButtonBaseStyleKey
        {
            get { return buttonBaseStyleKey; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's obviously a bug on ReSharper or on VS, first, don't post product bugs on S.O., this is a place to solve coding problems, second, try to install a fresh VS without ReSharper, if the problem doesn't happens then it's a bug with ReSharper, else it's a bug on VS, then you can fill a bug report on the appropiate support service.

Comment: @Gusman As I stated in the post, I did do this on a separate computer with no extensions. And I was not confident it was a bug (besides the actual blank entry) since I don't see anyone else complaining about it, which is why I am seeing if I'm doing anything wrong here.

Comment: Hmm, I thought you installed also ReSharper on the other machines. Ok, anyway, anything which locks the keyboard input is a bug, VS never disallows you to write anything on text editors indepenently of the monstrosity you wrote (I don't mean your code is a monstrosity, I mean you can just club your keyboard and VS will write what you typed ;) ), so yes, it's a bug. You can report VS bugs here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/support-overview-vs.aspx

Comment: @Gusman Well, I was planning on sending the bug report as well, but Microsoft is slow to respond to those and often don't offer solutions and I'm mainly just trying to see if there was a known workaround for this since I can't find anyone else having the issue for a fairly common task. Just the fact that I don't see any mention of this problem elsewhere makes me think I'm doing something wrong, but just so happens to cause a bug due to me doing something wrong.

Comment: I would agree on that if it weren't reproducible, but you very diligently did a lot of tests before on different machines and different versions of VS. Maybe you're using an structure a bit complicated for the intellisense system, but it is not an excuse to block the editor :D